# SQL tables decomposition with super-class for two ORM classes or CHECK constraint

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Let say we have a table where each row should have one or another foreign key – but one is mandatory. Something like this:

| id | name | fk1 | fk2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | 10 | NULL |
| 2 | second | NULL | 3 |

We may use table-level CHECK constraint for columns `fk1` and `fk2`:

```sql
CHECK (fk1 is not null or fk2 is not null) and (fk1 is null or fk2 is null)
```

However, I suppose that better way is to decompose one this table to two tables.

###### table1

| id | name | fk1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | 10 |

###### table2

| id | name | fk2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | second | 3 |

**Or perhaps it's not a best way? How do you think?**

Also, if choose this way, than I think about ORM models. *I'm using SQLAlchemy, and this is first time I use it in real project.* As far as I understand each table should have its own mapping class. But these classes will differ only in one attribute. **Maybe it's better to create a third class that will collect rows from both tables?** This class will share both foreign keys attributes. And will perform analogue of CHECK at constructor level.

Is it possible with SQLAlchemy or I need to implement it myself? Or you say it is somehow not good idea at all?

Thanks in advance!